# Archiving stuck at Facebook Login -- Xcode 11, Swift 5, macOS Catalina

Tags: xcode11, swift5, archiving

[image]

> Archiving App: FacebookLogin

I updated to Xcode 11 and archiving getting stuck at FacebookLogin. I am using FacebookLogin 5.7.0. Thanks.

Comment: pls help me also when you solved this